# How to fix ERROR 6: Unable to load PROJ.4 library (proj.dll), creation of OGRCoordinateTransformation failed issue

Tags: gdal, proj

I have installed GDAL in my system. I tried a simple program which uses spatial reference functions. When I tried to execute that program i am facing "ERROR 6: Unable to load PROJ.4 library (proj.dll), creation of
OGRCoordinateTransformation failed" issue. I have installed proj.4 also. I have also added proj.4 path in environment variable. Still I am facing this issue. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your program cannot find the proj.dll in system paths. 
It depends the source where you get libProj.4.

For example [NextGIS Installer](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/) or [OSGEO4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) have their own shell to execute scripts and programs with necessary paths set.

You can add path to proj.dll in PATH environment variable or use following command in command prompt.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;<path to proj.dll>
```

Also you can just put proj.dll in same folder with program.

The one more check is test proj.dll missed dependencies via [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libproj.so.0 /usr/lib/libproj.so`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems just the `ogr2ogr` file was copied over or something. Basically, GDAL was not properly installed.

When I properly installed [GDAL](https://gdal.org/download.html#conda) (through [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html) and `conda`) and reran the script, everything worked properly.